# Saving Custom UITableView detail views with SQlite?

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite, tableview, detailsview

I need some help saving custom detail view controllers. In my table view I have an add and edit button where the user can add and delete custom cells. Each cell goes to the same custom view, my only problem is that is there any way that I can save each cell using SQlite or another Database? I just don't want to have to create a ton of viewcontrollers and save each and every cell using NSUserDefaults.

My code :

table . h =

```
IBOutlet UITableView *warrantyTableView;

    NSMutableArray *data;
    IBOutlet UITextField *tableCellText;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
}

- (IBAction)addRowToTableView;
- (IBAction)editTable;
- (NSString *)dataFilePath;
- (IBAction)endText;
```

Table.m =

```
 - (NSString *)dataFilePath {

        NSString *dataFilePath;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        dataFilePath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"applicationData.plist"] retain];
        return dataFilePath;

    }

    - (void)saveData {

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[data copy]  toFile:[self dataFilePath]];

    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

         PushedViewController *pushedViewController = [[PushedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushedView" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
            PushedViewController *ifView = [[PushedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushedView" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:ifView animated:YES];
            [ifView release];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to save each cell in database ? Save all the data in the cells in SQLite. While accessing, get the data from SQLite database to an array of dictionary. The dictionary will contain all data of one cell, the array will contain all the dictionaries having the data of each cell. Then reload the tableview with the data from that array.     WWhile editing/adding/deleting objects to the tableview, do the whole operation first from the array of dictionary and then, when a single operation is finished, save it to the sqlite and again reload the tableview.